# how to extract a specific link value (page number) from a pagination in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, extract

i would like to extract the current link value from my codeigniter pagination in the controller and put it in a own variable.

```
the usual pagination code...

$str_links = $this->pagination->create_links(); 
$data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );
```

with print_r($data["links"]); i printed the array to check what i find inside.

```
result:
( Array ( [0] => [1] => 1234NextLast › )  
( Array ( [0] => Previous1 [1] => 2345NextLast › )  
( Array ( [0] => Previous12 [1] => 3456NextLast › ) and so on
```

i would like to extract the current page number and add it to a different variable.

```
... [1] => 1
... [1] => 2
... [1] => 3 and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get current page number from the url:

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

If it is in the third segment, you can count the segments or i prefer this:

```
$segment_array = $this->uri->segment_array();
$last_segment = end($segment_array);
```

And last segment should be your current page number.